# Finding the "nth attempt" using Tidyverse in R

Tags: r, indexing, count, tidyverse, summary

I have a dataset that shows the logins by date and unique_session_code for each user that visits the webpage of a bakery. I am trying to come a code that allows me to  determine if this is the first, second, third and so on... visit of this customer in other words the "nth_visit" and I am really looking for a solution using the tidyverse package, but if there is no way to do that using tidyverse then all other solutions are just as appreciated. thanks for the help guys!

| USER | LOG_DATE | TX_REV |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ALEX | 30/04/2021 | uyjd |
| MARY | 30/04/2021 | dn89 |
| DOLLY | 30/04/2021 | nqmd0 |
| FRANK | 29/04/2021 | nsj456 |
| MARY | 29/04/2021 | zlpa2 |
| DOLLY | 29/04/2021 | s09dm |
| ALEX | 28/04/2021 | jds02 |
| MARY | 28/04/2021 | kqos98 |
| DOLLY | 28/04/2021 | uiskk0 |

This would be my desired result:

| USER | LOG_DATE | TX_REV | nth_visit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ALEX | 28/04/2021 | jds02 | 1 |
| ALEX | 30/04/2021 | uyjd | 2 |
| DOLLY | 28/04/2021 | uiskk0 | 1 |
| DOLLY | 29/04/2021 | s09dm | 2 |
| DOLLY | 30/04/2021 | nqmd0 | 3 |
| FRANK | 29/04/2021 | nsj456 | 1 |
| MARY | 28/04/2021 | kqos98 | 1 |
| MARY | 29/04/2021 | zlpa2 | 2 |
| MARY | 30/04/2021 | dn89 | 3 |

A data frame that has the "nth_visit" to the website by each attempt of the visitor

**What have I done?**

I have tried to arrange the date in chronological order and group by ID, and reviewing some documentation I tried to use the function rank_dense but it does not give me the results that I am looking for..not even close.

Thank you so much guys

code:

```
df<-tibble::tribble(
  ~USER,    ~LOG_DATE,  ~TX_REV,
  "ALEX",       "30/04/2021",   "uyjd",
  "MARY",       "30/04/2021",   "dn89",
  "DOLLY",  "30/04/2021",   "nqmd0",
  "FRANK",  "29/04/2021",   "nsj456",
  "MARY",       "29/04/2021",   "zlpa2",
  "DOLLY",  "29/04/2021",   "s09dm",
  "ALEX",       "28/04/2021",   "jds02",
  "MARY",       "28/04/2021",   "kqos98",
  "DOLLY",  "28/04/2021",   "uiskk0")
```

Comment: use `row_number()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting by date will help, otherwise the visit numbering will be in order of appearance in the data rather than chronological.

```
df %>%
  mutate(LOG_DATE_DT = as.Date(LOG_DATE, "%d/%m/%Y")) %>%
  arrange(USER, LOG_DATE_DT) %>%
  group_by(USER) %>%
  mutate(nth_visit = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 9 x 5
  USER  LOG_DATE   TX_REV LOG_DATE_DT nth_visit
  <chr> <chr>      <chr>  <date>          <int>
1 ALEX  28/04/2021 jds02  2021-04-28          1
2 ALEX  30/04/2021 uyjd   2021-04-30          2
3 DOLLY 28/04/2021 uiskk0 2021-04-28          1
4 DOLLY 29/04/2021 s09dm  2021-04-29          2
5 DOLLY 30/04/2021 nqmd0  2021-04-30          3
6 FRANK 29/04/2021 nsj456 2021-04-29          1
7 MARY  28/04/2021 kqos98 2021-04-28          1
8 MARY  29/04/2021 zlpa2  2021-04-29          2
9 MARY  30/04/2021 dn89   2021-04-30          3
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is just what I wanted... I have a doubt when we are grouping then nrow() gives us the number of the row of that group instead of the name of the row of the entire set right?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this in tidyverse would be:

```
df %>% group_by(USER) %>% mutate(nth_visit = seq_along(USER)) %>% 
   ungroup() %>% arrange(USER, nth_visit)

# A tibble: 9 x 4
  USER  LOG_DATE   TX_REV nth_visit
  <chr> <chr>      <chr>      <int>
1 ALEX  30/04/2021 uyjd           1
2 ALEX  28/04/2021 jds02          2
3 DOLLY 30/04/2021 nqmd0          1
4 DOLLY 29/04/2021 s09dm          2
5 DOLLY 28/04/2021 uiskk0         3
6 FRANK 29/04/2021 nsj456         1
7 MARY  30/04/2021 dn89           1
8 MARY  29/04/2021 zlpa2          2
9 MARY  28/04/2021 kqos98         3
```